# I want to call java servlet from vb 6.0 button

Tags: vb6

I want to call java servlet from from my vb 6.0 code. I have tu use the URL of the servelet on remote machine and display the message after execution of the program.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You will get more help if you state an explicit, clear question, rather than a vague "I want to do X". Maybe providing a sample of what you need to call, what you've tried and how it failed or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim req As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim buffer As Variant
Set req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
req.SetTimeouts 1800000, 1800000, 1800000, 1800000
req.Open "POST", "http://www.google.co.in", False
buffer = "tusharp 0"
req.Send cmbuffer
Debug.Print req.ResponseText

End Sub
```

Try this.....

Answer (score 0):

Using following bunch of code you can simply call servlet by using URL. You can pass parameters via appropriate method.

```
**Private Function ExecuteSQL(ByVal sSQL As String, ByVal bResultSet As Boolean) As String
Dim http As Object
Dim strURL As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim strHeader As String
Dim strResponse As String

On Error GoTo Err

Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

strPostData = "?Command=" & IIf(bResultSet, "SELECT", "UPDATE") & "&SQL=" & sSQL

strURL = "http://localhost:8080/FirstProject/DBConnector" & strPostData
http.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000 'For some reason times out sooner than this sometimes

http.Open "POST", strURL, False
http.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.Send strPostData
strResponse = http.ResponseText

Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
ExecuteSQL = strResponse
Exit Function
```